# Why regular comments after doxygen line comments looks like preprocessor code?

Tags: formatting, doxygen

I wasn't able to find this anywhere, so...

This is my first Doxygen attempt.
I have a code in C and use Doxygen to generate the HTML documentation.

However, when I mix *block* and *line comments*, the resulting source code is not formatted correctly. Some comments (not doxygen) are rendered as acutal comments and some are shown as preprocessor lines.

This is a MWE source code:

```
#ifdef __DEFINES_H_
#define __DEFINES_H_

// this comment looks like a comment
/** error */
#define ERROR -1

// this is also ok
/** This is zero */
#define ZERO 0

// and so is this one
#define FIRST 1     /**< the first */

// but this comment is listed with class="preprocessor"
#define TEN 10      /**< just 10 */

// and this comment also looks like a preprocessor line
/** error */
#define ANOTHER_ERROR -1

// here the comment looks like a comment again
/** This is zero */
#define ANOTHER_ZERO 0

#endif // __DEFINES_H_
```

The HTML source code for this file is the following (sorry for the long lines).

```
<div class="line"><a name="l00002"></a><span class="lineno">    2</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">#define __DEFINES_H_</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00003"></a><span class="lineno">    3</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00004"></a><span class="lineno">    4</span>&#160;<span class="comment">// this comment looks like a comment</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00006"></a><span class="lineno">    6</span>&#160;<span class="comment"></span><span class="preprocessor">#define ERROR -1</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00007"></a><span class="lineno">    7</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00008"></a><span class="lineno">    8</span>&#160;<span class="comment">// this is also ok</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00010"></a><span class="lineno">   10</span>&#160;<span class="comment"></span><span class="preprocessor">#define ZERO 0</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00011"></a><span class="lineno">   11</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00012"></a><span class="lineno">   12</span>&#160;<span class="comment">// and so is this one</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00013"></a><span class="lineno">   13</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">#define FIRST 1     </span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00015"></a><span class="lineno">   15</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">// but this comment is listed with class=&quot;preprocessor&quot;</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00016"></a><span class="lineno">   16</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">#define TEN 10      </span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00018"></a><span class="lineno">   18</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">// and this comment also looks like a preprocessor line</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00019"></a><span class="lineno">   19</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00020"></a><span class="lineno">   20</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">#define ANOTHER_ERROR -1</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00021"></a><span class="lineno">   21</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00022"></a><span class="lineno">   22</span>&#160;<span class="comment">// here the comment looks like a comment again</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00024"></a><span class="lineno">   24</span>&#160;<span class="comment"></span><span class="preprocessor">#define ANOTHER_ZERO 0</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00025"></a><span class="lineno">   25</span>&#160; </div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00026"></a><span class="lineno">   26</span>&#160;<span class="preprocessor">#endif // __DEFINES_H_</span></div>
```

And this is how the browser shows it.

[image: Code in browser]

Lines 15 and 18 use `<span class="preprocessor">` when should use `<span class="comment">`.

As I can see, it happens after `/**<  */` comments.

But how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Version 1.8.17, from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it with the doxygen 1.8.13 version and here I can see the problem as indicated.
With the current 1.9.1 version the problem is gone.

In the 1.8.13 version the line 18 was marked as "preprocessor" and in version 1.9.1 it is marked as "comment"

This bug has been fixed between 1.8.13 and 1.9.1, so to fix it is to upgrade to newer version.
(it was actually fixed in 1.9.0, but it is better not to use 1.9.0 but 1.9.1).

Comment: I got version 1.9.1 from GIT and it worked great for this issue. Some fixing with blank lines still need some attention, as they are ignored afer `/**<` comments.

Comment: Can you give an example of the problem with the empty lines? (best as a new issue).

Comment: I'll get the time to post a new question. For now, I meant empty lines after `/*< */` are supressed.

Comment: Before trying to create an example, try the doxygen 1.9.1 version first.

Comment: The issue is present in version 1.9.2. You mean downgrading to 1.9.1 to test or just making sure a newer version is in use?
But I'll make some tests to check this. Perhaps I'm missing something. :-)

Comment: I assume you are talking about the empty lines, of which it is not clear whether or not this problem would still be present. When it is present in 1.9.2 (which is the current, not released master) it is very likely that it is present in 1.9.1 as well (otherwise we have a regression). So yes please try to create an example, so we can have a look.